# Derby Client side error i am getting , i have started setNetworkServerCP.bat and create database

Tags: derby

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server 196.236.236.61 on port 1527 with message Connection timed out: connect.
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hi Ashutosh, and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm not sure this site is the best place for your question - if you're struggling with connections to your new database, then perhaps http://dba.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Check your Windows Firewall settings, they may be blocking your connection.

Comment: Yes , i am working on windows , from different machine client is not able to access table of derby data base , i have given derbyclient.jar on client side already.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I made a server class in side which create a database and table inside it, put sum data .

```
public static String dbURL2 = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/DatabaseFord;create=true ";
```

now I am trying to access table content from client class from different machine

on the client side I have given

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        connect = DriverManager
                .getConnection("jdbc:derby://19.255.233.119:1527/databaseNAme;create=true");
```

then client from different machine not able to fetch the data of table .On client side i have given derby client .jar and i have already running the net ServerUtility'